# How to swap two nodes in binary tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, swap

In my BST class I am using the following function to swap two nodes

```
void swapNodes(BSTNode *node1, BSTNode *node2)
  {
    if(node1->parent->left==node1)
        node1->parent->left = node2;
     else
        node1->parent->right = node2;
     if(node2->parent->left==node2)
        node2->parent->left = node1;
     else
        node2->parent->right = node1;

    BSTNode *temp;
     temp->parent = node1->parent;
     temp->left = node1->left;
     temp->right = node1->right;

     node1->parent = node2->parent;
     node1->left = node2->left;
     node1->right = node2->right;

     node2->parent = temp->parent;
     node2->left = temp->left;
     node2->right = temp->right;
  }
```

It takes two node pointers and swap them both. But when I call this function it comes with an error of memory violation. What am I doing wrong here? If you know any other easy way to swap two nodes in a binary tree please share.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is more complicated than it seems, because of special cases involving the root of the tree, swapping two items when one is the other's parent, and fixing up the parent pointers of the left and right child items. Here is some code that works. I suspect that it could be made neater and shorter in some way.

```
    void Swap(T* aP,T* aQ)
    {
    T* new_p_parent = aQ->iParent;
    T* new_p_left = aQ->iLeft;
    T* new_p_right = aQ->iRight;
    T** new_p_link = &iRoot;
    if (aQ->iParent)
        new_p_link = aQ->iParent->iLeft == aQ ? &aQ->iParent->iLeft : &aQ->iParent->iRight;

    T* new_q_parent = aP->iParent;
    T* new_q_left = aP->iLeft;
    T* new_q_right = aP->iRight;
    T** new_q_link = &iRoot;
    if (aP->iParent)
        new_q_link = aP->iParent->iLeft == aP ? &aP->iParent->iLeft : &aP->iParent->iRight;

    if (aQ->iParent == aP)
        {
        new_p_parent = aQ;
        new_p_link = nullptr;
        if (aP->iLeft == aQ)
            new_q_left = aP;
        else
            new_q_right = aP;
        }
    else if (aP->iParent == aQ)
        {
        new_q_parent = aP;
        new_q_link = nullptr;
        if (aQ->iLeft == aP)
            new_p_left = aQ;
        else
            new_p_right = aQ;
        }

    aP->iParent = new_p_parent;
    aP->iLeft = new_p_left;
    if (aP->iLeft)
        aP->iLeft->iParent = aP;
    aP->iRight = new_p_right;
    if (aP->iRight)
        aP->iRight->iParent = aP;
    if (new_p_link)
        *new_p_link = aP;

    aQ->iParent = new_q_parent;
    aQ->iLeft = new_q_left;
    if (aQ->iLeft)
        aQ->iLeft->iParent = aQ;
    aQ->iRight = new_q_right;
    if (aQ->iRight)
        aQ->iRight->iParent = aQ;
    if (new_q_link)
        *new_q_link = aQ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BSTNode *temp;
```

is not initialized